# Assign a lambda (function) to a variable to be passed as parameter in Java

Tags: java, variables, lambda

How can I assign a lambda function to a variable for later use...

I want to store a lambda in a variable

```
<?type> lambda1 = ()->{ System.out.print( "whatever..." ) };
```

and then use it... or pass lambda1 as a parameter...

my question is what type should I use to declare lambda1
If this is even possible in Java...

If possible please state the first version of Java that supports this functionality...

Comment: You would declare as same type as parameter you'd want to pass it to. Or `Runnable` like Louis said, if you just want to use it directly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't think that's what they are asking about. I think they want to plug the lambda later. As in `SomeOtherFunctionalInterface val = lambda1;`. As an alias. Zee, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if you want to do that, then you can just store it as a `Runnable` and then pass `lambda1::run` wherever you need your other interface.  But I don't read the question that way anyway; I think the OP just wants an interface this lambda could be stored in.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sure.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the purpose... I read the alternate indicated answer and did not fill my needs,,, so I add more info...

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand. Can you explain how you then intend to use `lambda1`?

Comment: Sure... I usually use lambdas to simplify/amplify programs funcionality... the best example I can give come from Javascript/TypeScript/NodeJS/ES6... you can define a lambda as [    lambda1 = (a,b)=>{ print( a+b ) }    ]... and then through your code invoke lambda1(1,2)... or pass lambda1 as a parameter no anywhere (a object instance is the most logic) achieving functionality injection (you store and invoke the lambda in a method socket),,,

Comment: I mean something concrete. Where and how would you use it? Give an example.

Comment: Ok... nodeJS...   

o1 = { f1: null, f2: null }
o2 = { f1: null, f2: null }
f1 =(x)=>console.log(x);
o1.f1=f1;
o2.f2=f1;

as you can see... using a pseudo-pointer (the lambda variable) provided with the possibility to define the sockets of different objects with the same base functionality,,, ,,, ,,, but there is much more in this,,, this is a simple & quick showcase.,,, ;-)

Comment: I don't know node.js. I don't know what that does nor what `o1` or `f1` relates to in your question. This is completely unclear. @Louis below and the duplicate post has provided an answer if all you were looking for is a target type. If that's not what you are looking for, please clarify.

Comment: I use interfaces in other languages,,, c++ / c#,,, and that is not why I'm asking for,,, I already seek through the net and seems that Java is not at the level of C++ / C# in the lambda thing... I posted here the question to have feedback or more knowledge about this,,, thanks for your effort,,,

Comment: If you want to pass `lambda1` as a parameter of a method, you should declare it to have the type that the parameter of that method expects.

Answer (score 2):

`Runnable` would work here, since you have a no-arg lambda without a return value.